# SQL SERVER - Join with Calendar Table to get Weekend, bring value from Friday to Saturday and Sunday

Tags: sql-server, missing-data, with-statement, azure-synapse

I am trying to get Saturday and Sunday into current results and bring over  values from Friday to Saturday and Sunday.

My initial dataset:

```
create table AA as (userid varchar(10), return_date datetime,  first_date  
datetime);
insert into AA 
select ('A',  '2019-06-07', '2019-06-01 15:46:43.000')
union all 
select ('A',  '2019-06-10', '2019-06-01 15:46:43.000')
union all 
select ('B',  '2019-06-07', '2019-06-03 15:46:43.000')
union all 
select ('B',  '2019-06-10', '2019-06-03 15:46:43.000');
```

I have tried to use Full Outer Join/Cross Join/Lag/Lead but to no success. I want to avoid loop and I don't think this would require loop.

Also as Im working on Azure SQL DataWarehouse so there are a number of limits, e.g. recursive cte is limited.

This is the result I am looking for:

```
userid,     return_date,        first_date
A,          '2019-06-07',       '2019-06-01 15:46:43.000'
A,          '2019-06-08',       '2019-06-01 15:46:43.000'
A,          '2019-06-09',       '2019-06-01 15:46:43.000'
A,          '2019-06-10',       '2019-06-01 15:46:43.000'
B,          '2019-06-07',       '2019-06-03 15:46:43.000'
B,          '2019-06-08',       '2019-06-03 15:46:43.000'
B,          '2019-06-09',       '2019-06-03 15:46:43.000'
B,          '2019-06-10',       '2019-06-03 15:46:43.000'
```

Thanks for your help in advance. Really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I think this will work:

```
    select * from aa
    union
    select userid, dateadd(d,1,return_date) return_date, first_date from aa 
        where datepart(dw, return_date) = 6 -- only returns Fridays, translate to Sat
    union
    select userid, dateadd(d,2,return_date) return_date, first_date from aa 
        where datepart(dw, return_date) = 6 -- only returns Fridays, translate to Sun
    order by userid, return_date
```